# In SPL TEDA 4.2 , do we have limitation on number of input file types that can be included?

Tags: ibm-streams

I am working on TEDA v2.0.1 and SPL v4.2 . When I am trying to add more than 18 different input file types , the job is compiled successfully but at runtime, it is going to status 'no' without any error in logs.

I have faced this issue while developing multiple applications.

Answer (score 0):

Do you face the problem that pe trace files having size of 0 bytes?
The status "no" is related to job status?
How much memory does the zookeeper have? If jobs are getting bigger, than the Zookeeper might become the bottleneck, increase the heap size for the zookeeper helps in this case.

Comment: Here are my zookeeper properties:st getbootproperty -a
streams.zkmonitor.checkIntervalMs=50000
streams.zkmonitor.connTimeoutMs=5000
streams.zkmonitor.port=21820
streams.zookeeper.jvmFlags=-Xmx1024m
streams.zookeeper.logDir=/home/streams1/.streams/var/embeddedzk
streams.zookeeper.property.clientPort=34809
streams.zookeeper.property.dataDir=/home/streams1/.streams/var/embeddedzk/datadir
streams.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns=0
streams.zookeeper.property.maxSessionTimeout=180000
streams.zookeeper.property.minSessionTimeout=-1
streams.zookeeper.property.tickTime=3000

Comment: 4 GB heap size for Zookeeper is recommended for applications like ITE with many channels and operators

Comment: I tried increasing size to 4GB . Still job goes to unhealthy state with 0 size pe files.

Comment: Increase the trace level to debug and collect the logs for the Streams support team

Comment: I increased the trace level to debug while submitting the job, but still we ave got nothing in pe logs.Please suggest how to proceed further.

Comment: Support page seems to be in transition:
https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/topic/0TO50000000IQN0GAO/streams?language=en_US

You could ask on streams dev:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/streamsdev/index.html?language=en_US

Do not use TEDA in the topic since it is not a TEDA problem when PE logs are empty. It is rather a runtime/platform problem.

Please mention that the PE logs are empty even after increasing the trace level!